Nuxt.js website does not see environment variables while in production
Website works properly in development. In production, it launches but does not see environment variables. I have set up secrets as environment variables. Previously, I tried setting up environment variables directly (without using the secrets feature) and also setting them up in console inside deployment script. None of this worked. I am getting no error messages.
nuxt.config.js:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: { enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV != "production" },
    modules: [
        'nuxt-mongoose',
    ],
    devServer: {
        port: parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8080
    },
    server: {
        port: parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8080
    },
    app: {
        head: {
            script: [{
                src: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"
            }]
        }
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
        MONGODB_URI: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
        GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SERVER_KEY: process.env.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SERVER_KEY,
        public: {
            GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_CLIENT_KEY: process.env.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_CLIENT_KEY
        }
    }
})

Dockerfile:
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV PORT=8080
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", ".output/server/index.mjs"]

cloudbuild.yaml:
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  args:
  - build
  - "--tag=(my docker address here)"
  - "--file=./Dockerfile"
  - .
- name: node:18.16.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["install"]
- name: node:v18.16.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["run", "create-env"]
  env:
    - MONGODB_URI=${MONGODB_URI}
    - GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SERVER_KEY=${GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SERVER_KEY}
    - GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_CLIENT_KEY=${GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_CLIENT_KEY}
    - PORT=8080
    - HOST=0.0.0.0
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"

How to get the website to see environment variables (some of which are private) without violating security?

Nuxt has a different approach to environment variables, as the official docs descrive:


Only a specially-named environment variable can override a runtime config property. That is, an uppercase environment variable starting with NUXT_ which uses _ to separate keys and case changes.


and

Setting the default of runtimeConfig values to differently named environment variables (for example setting myVar to process.env.OTHER_VARIABLE) will only work during build-time and will break on runtime. It is advised to use environment variables that match the structure of your runtimeConfig object.

This means that any process.env you have in your nuxt.config.ts will remain dynamic only during dev.
To make them easily overwritable at runtime (after build) you should update the nuxt.config.ts as follows. So that Nuxt is aware that it should expect strings for those env variables.
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // what you already have above

  runtimeConfig: {
    mongodbUri: '',
    googleRecaptchaServerKey: '',
    public: {
      googleRecaptchaClientKey: ''
    }
  }
})

and then use the following env variables
NUXT_MONGODB_URI
NUXT_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SERVER_KEY
NUXT_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_CLIENT_KEY
NUXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_CLIENT_KEY

